# How to connect to Facebook account after login to the website?

Tags: facebook, connection

A user has an account on my website which is not connected to any Facebook account. He/she goes to a profile page on my website and there is a link: "Connect Facebook".

Now he/she clicks on it, authorizes the Facebook page, gets redirected back to my website. But it shows that you are connected to your Facebook account.  And in future if they want they can also disconnect their Facebook account.

Answer (score 0):

To connect their account you have two options: through the server side flow and through the client side. There are a few steps to this, but I'll walk you through an outline of the client side process.

**client side**

1. Initialize the [JavaScript sdk](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). Follow that all the way up to "calling the graph API". You will have to setup your website/app with facebook, to get an "app ID" and an "app secret" or "api secret" (it could be either of those name but I think it's "api").
2. once you're calling the graph api, you need to get a user's `uid` from facebook (the `uid` is unique to a user so that's where the relationship should occur), and whatever else you want (most things beyond name require additional permissions, but that should be in the above link). At that point you can customize their account.
3. make it so that a user can "delete" their `uid` from your database, and with it everything else that you've customized to it or retrieved from Facebook.

If you think that you'll need the server side authentication method, you should follow these [instructions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try following the steps.